# accept thunderbird invitation into evolution calendar

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, calendar, lightning, gnome-calendar

There are some annoyances I just put up with calendars in the linux environment such as that the Gnome calendar needs an evolution calendar backend and that when you 'accept' a calendar invitation in Thunderbird, you need to be sure the correct email account is set before doing so, so that the reply goes out from the correct email address.

Anyway I seem to have tamed my setup, Evolution is syncing with a remote CalDAV server, Gnome calendar displays Evolution meetings in a more appealing way.

A further improvement would be if upon clicking "accept invitation" in Thunderbird, the appointment were automatically saved into one specific calendar in Evolution rather than into the internal Thunderbird calendar 'Lightning' which I don't use.

It's very annoying, is there a way to make it do that?

Answer (score 0):

For now I have turned to this imperfect solution:

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/eds-calendar-integration/

Which has its GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/balbusm/xul-ext-eds-calendar)

After installation I switched off automatic updates, will rather wait a while and check them before installing. Just after installing it seemed that all Lightning events were pulled into Evolution which was what I wanted.

I just wonder if someone sent an invite to change the time of an appointment if pulling that event into Evolution would do the trick.

It is a one-way sync, and another point to note is that there is an older add-on which does the same thing for older Thunderbirds, be careful not to install that.

Does anyone know *when* this add-on does its syncing? Is it as soon as Thunderbird is opened, even when it is closed, at periodic time intervals or constantly?

Anyway, it is a solution of sorts but it would be cleaner if the appointments just went straight from Thunderbird into Evolution without passing through Lightning.